# How to convert this Hibernate Criteria query to instead use javax.jpa.CriteriaQuery Multiple Root Entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria, hibernate-criteria

Since the hibernate.criteria API is deprecated, I need assistance converting certain methods to JPA criteriaQuery.

The simpler calls with singular criteria and limited parameters I can handle, but how can I convert from a hibernate criteria created with multiple root entities. Here is the org.hibernate.criteria code that needs conversion

```
Criteria crit = 
session.createCriteria(getType())
.createCriteria("deviceInfo"
.createCriteria("deviceSize");
crit.add(Restrictions.ilike("upperName", modelName));

List<Device> matches = crit.list();
```

The conversion for something like this with a singular call to createCriteria I can manage. They look something like this

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Workflow> cq = cb.createQuery(getType());
Root<getType()> model = cq.from(getType());
cq.select(model);
cq.where(cb.equal(model.get("primaryEntityId"), entityId));
TypedQuery<getType()> q = entityManager.createQuery(cq);
List<Workflow> matches = q.getResultList();
```

The only thing I can't seem to recreate in JPA is the two association paths passed in to createCriteria

Comment: I don't know Hibernate criteria API, but if you would show me what SQL the first one generates I would probably be able to help you writing that in JPA. You can have multiple roots in JPA criteria, if you do you have to select only one or get a result as an `Object[]` like `cb.createQuery(Object[].class)`.

Comment: Could you show me an example of a couple lines that do that? cb.createQuery(object.class) is what Im doing now for singular entities